# Parametrized update query with CAST function

Tags: sql, sql-server, prepared-statement, parameterized-query

I am using an update query as follows:

```
 UPDATE PeopleTable 
     SET firstname = CAST(REPLACE(CAST(firstname as nvarchar(max)), 'John', 'ReplacedFirstName') as ntext)
```

I would like to do the same for several first names like "Dave, Tom, Harry, Rick, Nick"

How do I do this correctly?

I tried something like this:

```
 create procedure proc2
 @sp varchar(25)
 as
 select UPDATE PeopleTable SET first name = CAST(REPLACE(CAST(BODY as
       nvarchar(max)), searchString = @sp,'ReplacedFirstName') as ntext)
 go


 declare @sp varchar(25)

 //I want to loop here and execute the stored proc for a list of names
 set @sp = 'name'     
 exec proc2 @sp
```

Comment: `CAST(SomeValue as next)`?   What's that supposed to do?

Comment: @Tab, we have many use cases where we need to replace certain strings, like update changed names or retire certain values

Comment: I now see that you had a typo, and `next` was supposed to be `ntext`.

Comment: @Tab, I don't see any next there. I could only see ntext.

Comment: You don't see that in your first code snippet you wrote:   `SET firstname = CAST(REPLACE(CAST(firstname as nvarchar(max)), 'John', 'ReplacedFirstName') as next)`?   I still see it there.

Comment: okay, now I see it, thank you, edited!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;

    String query = "UPDATE PeopleTable SET firstname = CAST(REPLACE(CAST(firstname as nvarchar(max)), ? ,'ReplacedFirstName') as ntext)";

    pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
    for(String s: myList) {

    pstmt.setString(1, s);

    pstmt.addBatch();

    }

    pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cte` with value construct

```
with t as (
       select *
       from ( values ('John', 'ReplacedFirstName'), ('Dave', 'ReplacedFirstName'),
                      . . .
            ) tt (firstname, ReplacedFirstName)
 )

update p 
      set p.firstname = t.ReplacedFirstName
from PeopleTable p inner join
     t 
     on t.firstname = p.firstname;
```

Comment: Thanks Yogesh, but I donot want to hardcode the first names, because I wouldn't know the first names to be replaced and even how many first names to be replaced until runtime.  Because the names to be replaced comes from the properties file